# How to read data from usb device on android device in android?

Tags: android, usb

I want to design an android application, in which it should read data from an USB device connected to it per standard timings.Can I? How?

Comment: U will definately got solution from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Answer (score 5):

You Can use [USB HOST OR ACCESSORY MODE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) for communicating with a USB device:

> Android supports a variety of USB peripherals and Android USB
>   accessories through two modes: **USB accessory** and **USB host**.
>
> [image]
>
> In USB accessory mode, the external USB hardware act as the USB hosts.
>   Examples of accessories might include robotics controllers; docking
>   stations; diagnostic and musical equipment; kiosks; card readers; and
>   much more.
>
> In USB host mode, the Android-powered device acts as the host.
>   Examples of devices include digital cameras, keyboards, mice, and game
>   controllers. USB devices that are designed for a wide range of
>   applications and environments can still interact with Android
>   applications that can correctly communicate with the device.

Like go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) for communicating with a device in HOST mode.

Comment: Shiv,, I need more explanation, as i am new to android environment.

Comment: yes i know thats why i have typed the link click on that and read ... ok i am editing my answer with some explanation also just go through this link and you will find ur answer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Comment: If you copy text from another site, please be sure to quote it and be clear about the attribution. I've edited the above to have this.