# How to read&write data from the micro USB on an Android smartphone

Tags: android, usb, smartphone

I am looking for some help about how to read/write data from the micro USB on an Android smartphone.

For example, my laptop sends data through its USB port where my Android smartphone is connected. I would like to log, or catch these data on the smartphone.

The main idea is to create a bridge from two devices thanks to two smartphones. To illustrate my thought, let's imagine I have a USB mouse connected to a smartphone, and on another side, another smartphone connected to a computer. I would make enable the use of the mouse on the computer using my two smartphones connected under the same network.

Any ideas about some existing solutions? Any thought how to log the USB data programatically?

Many thanks,

Comment: Seems like it was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/15172651/7567578

Comment: Cheers guys, I'll have a look to it.